# How do I skip a row in a recordset?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I need to iterate over all rows returned from a pass-through query. There will either be no rows returned or there will be 2+ rows returned where one of them will have a value of 1 for the column SkipRow. I need to iterate over any row that isn't this skippable row.

Below is what I've tried. The problem is that when I do `rs.MoveNext`, it continues through the loop but I need it to move to the next record and restart the loop when it encounters a skippable row.

```
   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

   Do While Not rs.EOF  

      intSkipRow = rs("SkipRow")

      If intSkipRow = 1 Then
         rs.MoveNext
      End If
      
      'Do stuff for any real rows
   
      rs.MoveNext
   Loop
```

Comment: Use an `else` in your `if`?

Comment: @Warcupine oh yea, I guess that works too

Comment: Your structure is a little off, on skip rows, you skip 2 rows because of the extra `rs.MoveNext`. A better structure is just `If Not intSkipRow Then` and put all your code in there, with `rs.MoveNext` after the `End If`

Comment: < *scratching my head* >...   It's a database recordset.  Why aren't you adding the SkipRow condition as a Where clause on your SQL to define the recordset?  Then you only get the rows you want to process.

Comment: I second what @ChrisMaurer said - especially considering the huge performance increase with bigger data sets.

Comment: @Toddleson yea I ended up doing something like what Warcupine suggested and now I only `rs.MoveNext` only once per loop.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer because I'm displaying the row to the end user, I just don't want to do VBA stuff to it.

Answer (score 1):

Is yours now like this?

```vb
   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

   Do While Not rs.EOF  

      intSkipRow = rs("SkipRow")

      If intSkipRow <> 1 Then
      
             'Do stuff for any real rows

      End If

      rs.MoveNext

   Loop
```